# Simple regex to match strings containing <n> chars

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing this regexp as i need a method to find strings that does not have n dots, 
I though that negative look ahead would be the best choice, so far my regexp is:

```
"^(?!\\.{3})$"
```

The way i read this is, between start and end of the string, there can be more or less then 3 dots but not 3.
Surprisingly for me this is not matching `hello.here.im.greetings`
Which instead i would expect to match.
I'm writing in Java so its a Perl like flavor, i'm not escaping the curly braces as its not needed in Java
Any advice?

Comment: Here you have a Regular Expression Test Page : http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
"^(?!(?:[^.]*\\.){3}[^.]*$)"
```

will work as expected.

Your regex means

```
^          # Match the start of the string
(?!\\.{3}) # Make sure that there aren't three dots at the current position
$          # Match the end of the string
```

so it could only ever match the empty string.

My regex means:

```
^       # Match the start of the string
(?!     # Make sure it's impossible to match...
 (?:    # the following:
  [^.]* # any number of characters except dots
  \\.   # followed by a dot
 ){3}   # exactly three times.
 [^.]*  # Now match only non-dot characters
 $      # until the end of the string.
)       # End of lookahead
```

Use it as follows:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?!(?:[^.]*\\.){3}[^.]*$)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
```

Comment: Hi Tim, i'm afraid this is not really correct, both (a.b.c.d) and (a.b.c) will return false,

Comment: @Lindrian: You're right; I had assumed he was looking for three dots in a row (I just looked at the regex, not at his example). Thanks for alerting me

Comment: @TimPietzcker , it does not really seems to work, with "hi.blabla.54589.......xl" will return false, which should not be the case, more then 3 dots should return true,

Comment: Did you use the regex in the way I detailed in my answer? If you're using the `.matcher()` method (which I would advise against because it forces you to match the entire string even though you may stop matching after the third dot), you have to add a `.*` at the very end of the regex.

Comment: Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?!(?:[^.]*\\.){3})");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("hi.blabla.54589.......xl");
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.find());

Comment: @JBoy: Oh! I really should have read your question more thoroughly. My regex was checking only for three or more, not for *exactly three* dots. Now it should work. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your regular expression only matches 'not' three consecutive dots. Your example seems to show you want to 'not' match 3 dots anywhere in the sentence.</strike>

Try this: `^(?!(?:.*\\.){3})`

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/bS0qW1

Check out Tims answer instead.

Comment: This is correct but very inefficient because `.*` will also match dots. Also, the final `.*` is unnecessary unless you're using the `.matches()` method.

Comment: You are correct @TimPietzcker. I had overseen that. Thanks for the pointer. On a completely unrelated note, is there any way of contacting you?

Comment: Check out my latest edit - we both had read the question wrong. And check your mailbox at regex101 :) Great site, by the way!

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Ah, the question was not abundantly clear in that regard. Thanks!